# Manage pending transactions/two-phase commits

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using Morhpia in my java app to communicate with MongoDb.

I have the following use case: 
I have two collections, one represents active users and some data about them, the other represents their accounts and their data. Base on some logic, I fire a method to delete all documents from these collections and then insert new lists of documents to each. Currently, that is exactly what I do: perform delete operations, and then insert operations. 
But I had a problem with an ungraceful shutdown, occurred exactly in the time interval between delete and persistence. That ended up in only partial data persisted. I would like to handle this case using a rollback, as I would with SQL.

I read about mongo shell offers some transactions management, such "Two-Phase Commits", that implements rollback if some set of operations were not successfully executed. I could not find any API in Morhpia to do the same. Is there a way to achieve pending transactions with Morphia?

Comment: You have to do it manually. Two-Phase-Commits aren't an API call, but a procedure. 99 times out of 100, however, the need for two phase commits is caused by wrong data modelling. Tell us your use cases(!), show us the models you have come up with and maybe you will get an answer on how to make your use case more efficient without using two phase commits.

Comment: My case if this: delete everything from two collections (one after the other), then save new lists of documents to each of these empty collections.
If for some reason the saving process fails, I would like to "revert" the deletion.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47375110/edit) accordingly. And this is not a use case. This is a technical description of what you do. A use case would be something like "I have users and books. I want the users to be able to rent books and...". And show us the models you have come up so far. Please do not make something up. Be straight, precise and complete.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post to be as accurate as possible for my specific problem